# how to profile .net garbage collector?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I'd like to know how to profile the performance of the garbage collector and monitor the three generations.  I wonder if it is possible to know at any point in time what are the current objects living in `gen0,gen1,gen2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get [useful information on GC performance from PerfMon](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/maoni/archive/2004/06/03/148029.aspx) - not as granular as you want though.

> There are many .NET Memory Performance
>   Counters and this is meant to give you
>   some guidelines in interpreting the
>   counter data and how to correlate
>   them. This assumes you have a basic
>   understanding of GC.

If you have one of the premium versions of Visual Studio that includes [Performance/Profiling Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264966.aspx), you can get more info on individual object allocations and lifetimes.  Specifically, this might be in the area you wished:

> The garbage collector reclaims memory
>   by deallocating a whole generation of
>   objects. For objects that the profiled
>   application created, the Object
>   Lifetime view displays the number and
>   size of the objects and the generation
>   when they are reclaimed.

If you are feeling really adventurous, you can do custom profiling using the [Profiling Tools API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514149.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[The CLR profiler could do this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx), but I don't think it is actively updated i.e for 3.5, 4.0, for 2.0 targeted apps, you can do this with the linked version.

Answer (score 1):

Check out JetBrains DotTrace.